# Unable to access ActiveMQ admin page /admin/. Reason: Unauthorized

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am trying to follow tutorial for ActiveMQ. 
After starting ActiveMQ from command prompt using **activemq-admin.bat start**
I am trying to access http://localhost:8161/admin/  to create new queues, but it throws me an error.  (I can access http://localhost:8161/)

```
HTTP ERROR: 401
Problem accessing /admin/index.jsp. Reason:
Unauthorized
```

Can anyone please suggest me any solution for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It Turned out to be Browser issue.
It worked on Internet Explorer and not on Chrome

Comment: use admin/admin if asks for credentials

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to access the page without logging in. 
To log in: 
Go to localhost:portNo/admin    portNo= 8161 if not modified
You will be prompted with login popup
username: admin
password: admin
The above are the default values.
If it's wrong, have a look at conf/jetty-realm.properties file.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't help at all. The message given is what happens *after* a successful login

Comment: In IE it asks for credentials, admin/admin works fine as they are default. Chrome didn't allow that popup to open.

Answer (score 0):

I am using apache activemq version 5.16.3. And on my machine It did work on chrome/internet explorer but not on edge.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30096998)

Answer (score 0):

It was also not working for me on Microsoft Edge and i can't user another browser at work.

But you can change the settings in the underlying jetty.

Goto jetty.xml in your Installation folder /conf:

```
    <bean id="securityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
        <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
        <property name="roles" value="users,admins" />
        <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
        <property name="authenticate" value="**false**" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="adminSecurityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
        <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
        <property name="roles" value="admins" />
         <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
        <property name="authenticate" value="**false**" />
    </bean>
```

and set authenticate to false. No login required.